# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-studio, android-asynctask, android-spinner

I am new to the android studio. my project is working fine on eclipse IDE. I just imported eclipse project into the **android studio**.
I am trying to load the states into the spinner. the spinner is on the dialog box. i am using AsyncTask to get the states and fill them in spinner. The same code is working fine in eclipse but in android studio it is giving me error as

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()' on a null object reference
```

following is the code for that class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import NWpackageHyp.AccessNwData;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Dialog;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.PreferenceManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Login extends Activity 
{
    EditText edusername,edpassword;
    Button registration;
    String username,password,state;
    int userid=0;
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    boolean status=false;
     Spinner spinner;
     ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter;
     ConnectionDetector Internet;
     List<String> stateList = new ArrayList<String>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login);
        Internet=new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

        edusername=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtxtusername);
        edpassword=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.edtxtpassword);
        registration=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
        final GetState asyncstate=new GetState();
        if(!Internet.isConnectingToInternet())
        {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Check Internet Connection!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else
        {
            asyncstate.execute();
        }

        registration.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if(Internet.isConnectingToInternet())
                {
                    showDialog(0);
                    asyncstate.execute();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Check Internet Connection!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    public Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
    {
        final Dialog builder=new Dialog(this);
        switch(id)
        {
        case 0:
            builder.setContentView(R.layout.regdialog);
            builder.setTitle("Registeration");

            spinner = (Spinner)builder.findViewById(R.id.spnState);
            final EditText username=(EditText)builder.findViewById(R.id.edtxtregusername);
            final EditText password=(EditText)builder.findViewById(R.id.edtxtregpassword);
            final EditText repassword=(EditText)builder.findViewById(R.id.edtxtrepassword);

            spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, stateList);
            spinnerAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spinner.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);

            Button registernow=(Button)builder.findViewById(R.id.btnRegisternow);
            registernow.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    final String uname,pass,repass,statestr;
                    statestr=(String) spinner.getSelectedItem();
                    uname=username.getText().toString();
                    pass=password.getText().toString();
                    repass=repassword.getText().toString();
                    if(!statestr.equals("") && !uname.equals("") && !pass.equals(""))
                    {
                        if(pass.equals(repass))
                        {
                            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),statestr+" "+uname+" "+pass+" "+repass , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                    System.out.println("run ");
                                    AccessNwData nwobj=new AccessNwData();
                                    try{
                                    String res=nwobj.registerUser(statestr, uname, pass);
                                    System.out.println("soham "+res);
                                     JSONArray jlogin = new JSONArray(res);                        
                                     JSONObject regObj = (JSONObject) jlogin.getJSONObject(0);
                                     if(regObj.getString("status").equals("true"))
                                     {
                                         runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                               @Override
                                               public void run() {
                                                   Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Registred Successfully You Can Login Now ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                                   username.setText("");
                                                   password.setText("");
                                                   repassword.setText("");
                                                   builder.hide();
                                               }
                                           });
                                     }
                                     else
                                    if(regObj.getString("status").equals("USER_EXIST"))
                                    {
                                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                               @Override
                                               public void run() {
                                                   Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Username already exists. please enter a different Username", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                               }
                                           });
                                    }
                                     else
                                     {
                                         runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {


                                               @Override
                                               public void run() {
                                                   Toast.makeText(Login.this, " Registration UnSuccessfull", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                          
                                               }
                                           });

                                     }
                                    }
                                    catch(final Exception e)
                                    {
                                        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {


                                               @Override
                                               public void run() {
                                                   Toast.makeText(Login.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                          
                                               }
                                           });
                                    }
                                }
                            }).start();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password Do Not Match", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please Fill All Fields", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
            return builder;
        }
        return null;
    }

    public class GetState extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(Login.this);
            pDialog.setMessage("Fetching States...");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
            AccessNwData jsonParser = new AccessNwData();
            String json = jsonParser.getState();
            System.out.println("got "+json);
            if(!json.equals("false"))
            {
                Log.e("log_tag", "> " + json);
                if (json != null) {
                    try {                   
                           JSONArray jstate = new JSONArray(json);  
                           for(int i=0;i<jstate.length();i++)
                           {
                               JSONObject stateObj = (JSONObject) jstate.getJSONObject(i);
                               stateList.add(stateObj.getString("name"));

                           }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                } else {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Didn't receive any data from server!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Log.e("log_tag", "Didn't receive any data from server!");
                        }
                    });
                }
            }else{
                 runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Problem Fetching State", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });
            }

            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            if (pDialog.isShowing())
                pDialog.dismiss();
            spinnerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPause();
        finish();
    }


}
```

LogCat:

```
12-01 11:54:26.121  19624-19624/global.get.mater/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: global.get.vancampaign, PID: 19624
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()' on a null object reference
            at global.get.vancampaign.Login$GetState.onPostExecute(Login.java:353)
            at global.get.vancampaign.Login$GetState.onPostExecute(Login.java:294)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:651)
            at android.os.AsyncTask.-wrap1(AsyncTask.java)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:668)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:'

```
  if(!Internet.isConnectingToInternet())
    {

    }
    else
    {
        asyncstate.execute();  //<< this line causing issue
    }
```

Because in this cause when `onPostExecute` method is called, `spinnerAdapter` object of `ArrayAdapter` is `null` because it is initialized only when `onCreateDialog` method called.

So, to get it work call `onCreateDialog` method before executing AsyncTask :

```
if(!Internet.isConnectingToInternet())
        {
           // your code here...   
        }
        else
        {
            showDialog(0);
            asyncstate.execute();  //<< this line causing issue
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error shows that `spinnerAdapter` is null,it's because your `spinnerAdapter` is created in `onCreateDialog`,but you never call it.Please check this.

Comment: what do you mean by this ??? 
can you provide a link or something .. please edit your answer